# 配列arrayの列を統一できない

Tags: python, numpy

以下データの列統一しようとするできない。なぜでしょうか。

以下df3データ

```
array([list([-1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 3, 7, 8, 9]),
list([-1, 10, 11, 10, 12, 13, 14, 13, 15, 13, 16, 13, 17, 13, 18]),dtype=object)
```

上記データの列をそろえようと以下コートです。

コードpython

```
X = sum(df3.tolist(), [])
## Max size
l = max(map(len, X))
## Padding
B = np.array(map(lambda x: x + [0]*(l-len(x)), X))
```

以下エラー内容

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-d279312ff4d1> in <module>
----> 1 X = sum(df3.tolist(), [])
      2 ## Max size
      3 l = max(map(len, X))
      4 ## Padding
      5 B = np.array(map(lambda x: x + [0]*(l-len(x)), X))

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'tolist'
```

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: `'list' object has no attribute 'tolist'` と表示されていますので、`df3` はリストであって、`numpy.array` 型のオブジェクトではない、という事になります。

Comment: Jupyter Notebook上で作業されているようですが、作業中に `df3` がリストになっていたりしませんか？　一度リセットしてセルを上から再実行しても同じエラーが出ますか？

Answer (score 1):

こちら解決しました。
勘違いして配列かと思ってました。リストでした。